# I was messing around at home and accidentally hit one of lightbulbs, now they won't turn on

Tags: light

A metal band hit one of my light bulbs and then all the lights off. I tried replacing all of my bulbs, but nothing worked. Please help!

Comment: its probably breaker tripped or fuse blown,

Comment: @Jasen - just put that as an answer.   Unless the bulb was owned by an evil demon of darkness, this is the only logical explanation...

Comment: "hit one of my light bulbs" *and broke it?* Otherwise you might want to investigate why hitting the fixture caused a breaker to trip.